# How to execute a .cql file inside a kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes, cql, cqlsh

I need to execute a .cql file inside a kubernetes pod.

I did not try anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **To execute the .cql file inside a pod:**

1>**copy the file to a pod:**

```
kubectl cp /path/of/the/file/.cql/ -n keyspace-name pod-name:/file/path/inside/the/pod -c name-of-container
```

2>**ssh to cassandra pod**:

```
kubectl exec -it pod-name -n keyspace-name -- bash
```

3>**run the .cql file:**

```
cqlsh -f/file/path/inside/the/pod
```